# R: force install package and dependancies in user library

Tags: r, installation

Apologies if this has been answered before but I can't find any related answer.

Is there an option to force install packages in R and their dependencies in a user library even if they exists on a common/system library?

For example, package "viridis" requires "viridisLite", however if the later is installed on the system library it will not be automatically installed on the user library when installing "viridis". This can cause some errors.

Comment: `library(pacman)` has a handy little function called `p_load` which is a wrapper for `require` and `library`. Would something like that do the trick?

Comment: @tomasu I tested `pacman` but it still installs the requested packages (e.g. "viridis") but the dependency package "viridisLite" which exists in the system library is not installed in the user library automatically.